# undestanding grid templates areas

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I am practicing with the grid, now I was trying the grid template areas, but one thing is not clear to me compared to the example I am following:

HTML:

```
 <div id="app">
   <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item1">Sono l'1</div>
    <div class="grid-item2">Sono il 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item3">Sono il 3</div>
    <div class="grid-item4">Sono il 4</div>
    <div class="grid-item5">Sono il 5</div>
    <div class="grid-item6">Sono il 6</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .grid-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   gap: 5px;
   grid-template-areas:
     'area1 area1 area1 area1 area1'
     'area2 area2 . area3 area3'
     'area2 area2 area4 area4 area4';
 }

 .grid-item1 {
   background: blue;
   text-align: center;
   border: black 5px solid;
   grid-area: area1;
 }

 .grid-item2 {
   background: red;
   text-align: center;
   border: black 5px solid;
   grid-area: area2;
 }

 .grid-item3 {
   background: green;
   text-align: center;
   border: black 5px solid;
   grid-area: area3;
 }
 .grid-item4 {
   background: yellow;
   text-align: center;
   border: black 5px solid;
   grid-area: area4;
 }
```

the example I followed says "If you don't want to assign a cell but leave it blank, just insert a period.", but how come in my exercise in that empty central cell the div 5 is inserted? I was expecting the 5 to go below before the 6....

I have also created a stackblitz for those who want more understanding:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-tfljyr?file=style.css

Comment: If you only define 4 areas, any extra elements will fit in wherever they can. Not defining a name for an area does not mean that it does not exist.

Comment: then the div 5 has gone to take the first empty space even if in the css I have inserted the point?
How was I supposed to write it to keep it from going to the center?

Comment: Define where you want it to be.